# Boto3 different outputs

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to get the instance id of ec2 that I created. But I get 2 different outputs, why? Please check the print outputs.

```
print (a) 
i-0ae514dcs36chb154
```

```
print (instance) 
ec2.Instance(id='i-0ae514dcs36chb154')
```

```
    ec=ec2.create_instances(
        ImageId=ami,
        InstanceType=type,
        MinCount=size,
        MaxCount=size,
        KeyName=keyname,
        SecurityGroupIds=[sg],
        TagSpecifications=[
            {
                'ResourceType': 'instance',
                'Tags': [
                    {
                        'Key': 'Name',
                        'Value': name,
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    )

    a= ec[0].id
    print (a) # Output: i-0ae514dcs36chb154
    instance = ec2.Instance(a)
    print (instance) # Output : ec2.Instance(id='i-0ae514dcs36chb154')
```

Thansks.

Comment: Print `instance.instance_id` if you want the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen here:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances

When you call `create_instances()` it returns a list of `ec2.Instance()` which is an object with an attribute `id`.

When you write,

```
a = ec[0].id  # Create a variable called "a" that points to the value of the "id" attribute of the first element in the list
print(a)  # print the id
```

When you write,

```
a = ec[0].id  # Create a variable called "a" that points to the value of the "id" attribute of the first element in the list
print(ec2.Instance(a))  # Create a new instance of ec2.Instance() with id equal to the value at a, then call the .__str__ method, and print
```

^ this is actually redundant.

Calling `print(ec[0])` should yield `ec2.Instance(id='i-0ae514dcs36chb154')`

So, the reason they are different is that in the first you are printing the value of the attribute `id` of the `ec2.Instance()` object. In the second you are printing the `ec2.Instance()` object itself, which will call the private method `__str__` on the `ec2.Instance()` object in order to produce a string to print.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Do you know, how can I get instance-id when I create ec2? I would like to find the instance state as follows.

`instance = ec2.Instance('i-0d36b21b215a75c88')
print (instance.state['Name'])
`

Comment: @Mr.Tux The documentation AWS has is pretty good for the most part. I usually just go directly there to figure out the answers.